# ERROR: Connection refused when connecting to socket server

Tags: java, c, sockets

I have the following C_Client code running well when using 3 terminals,
2 servers and 1 client.

However, when I deployed the same set of codes to 3 different machines,
it doesn't perform as expected.

There are few scenarios,

I am using 8888 port for server1 and 5678 port for server2. The input argument is for client to input.

1. Connect client and servers on the same machines - work as expected
   with argu input: `127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 8888 5678`
2. Connect client and server2 on the same machines, server1 on the other machines, it also works, with arguments input: `192.168.28.116 127.0.0.1 8888 5678`
3. The problematic scenario, connect client and server2 on different machines, no matter what I have done (such as turn off all firewalls, checking the port if listening or not), the error msg is shown: **`ERROR connecting tpserver:connection refused`**.

The argu input:

`192.168.28.116 192.168.28.117 8888 5678` or

`127.0.0.7 192.168.28.117 8888 5678`

From 2, it is sure that the connection on same machine or different machine on server1 doesn't matter, but when connecting server2 on different machine, it weirdly shows error when connecting to server1 socket? Why?

Client.c

```
//Variable declaration
int sockfd, sockfd2, portno, portno2, n, a, pid, startonce;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, serv_addr2;
struct hostent *server, *server2; 

//Opening socket
portno = atoi(argv[3]);
portno2 = atoi(argv[4]);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if ((sockfd < 0) || (sockfd2 < 0)) {
    error("ERROR opening socket");
}
server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
server2 = gethostbyname(argv[2]);
if (server == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

//Serv_addr for tpServer
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {    
    error("ERROR connecting tpserver");  
}

//Serv_addr for resultServer
bzero((char *) &serv_addr2, sizeof(serv_addr2));
serv_addr2 = serv_addr; 
serv_addr2.sin_port = htons(portno2);  
if (connect(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr2, sizeof(serv_addr2)) < 0) {    
    error("ERROR connecting resultserver");  
}
```

Server1.c

```
//Declare variables here
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
socklen_t clilen;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided\n");
    exit(1);
}

//Opening socket
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) {    
    error("ERROR opening socket");
}

//Filling info for serv_addr
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    error("ERROR on binding");
}
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

//Fork when there a successful connection
while (1) {
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) {
        error("ERROR on accept");
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        error("ERROR on fork");
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(sockfd);
        dostuff(newsockfd);
        exit(0);
    }
    else close(newsockfd);
}
close(sockfd);
return 0; 
}
```

Server2.java

```
public void startServer(final int portno) {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portno);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

        while (true) {                
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Update 2016/5/17 11:44

I changed the code from :

```
//Serv_addr for resultServer
bzero((char *) &serv_addr2, sizeof(serv_addr2));
serv_addr2 = serv_addr; //Copied tpServer socket to resultServer info for local testing
serv_addr2.sin_port = htons(portno2);  
if (connect(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr2, sizeof(serv_addr2)) < 0) {    
    error("ERROR connecting resultserver");  
}
```

to

```
//Serv_addr for resultServer
bzero((char *) &serv_addr2, sizeof(serv_addr2));
serv_addr2.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server2->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr2.sin_addr.s_addr, server2->h_length);
serv_addr2.sin_port = htons(portno2);  
if (connect(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr2, sizeof(serv_addr2)) < 0) {    
    error("ERROR connecting resultserver");  
}
```

But I still getting the same error message:

```
./tp_client 192.168.28.152 192.168.28.130 8888 5678
ERROR connecting tpserver: Connection refused
```

Update 2016/5/17 11:49

I tried using another linux machine and it connected to both server successfully, but when I set up the server2 on windows, it still shows connection refused.

So now, it works on 3 different linux but not linux to windows? I tested my server on windows with browser and it works like charm. How do I connect my linux client to windows server?

Update 2016/5/18 10:52

New discovery, when client connect to 2 servers, the 2 ips must be the same rather than on 2 different server machines, no matter windows or not.If they are the same, the connection is established,if not, connection refused. i included the perror() function but still getting the same msg: connection refused, is there any problem when i declare socket in client.c?

Comment: You code can't generate the error listed. Please improve question.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by can't generate the error listed? I think error("ERROR connecting tpserver"); would generate msg: ERROR connecting tpserver:connection refused. Or otherwise i really have no idea how to track and fix it.

Comment: I guess this line makes it happened, serv_addr2 = serv_addr; , i will try to fix it and report to see if anything related to this

Comment: You are ignoring the address provided for server2, and using the address provided for server 1 for both connects. Therefore you should get errors connecting to server 2, not server 1.

Comment: Please check update/edit, what should i be changed to correct it? It sounds like no problem at all

Comment: As you say its working fine on same machine. but got problem on different machine. So it may be possible due to firewall of machine and/or firewall of your network's router.

Comment: Just have no idea why it fails to connect to windows machine, i am now happily working with all linux machine but i still wanna know howcome it fails

Comment: As for my original comment, it appears including the error() function would have resolved it.

Comment: @Joshua sorry but may you please tell me where to include the error() function or what does it do?

Comment: @PSo He means including it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end, it turns out that the method:gethostbyname is deprecated and failed to response to the request. After updated to the method:getaddrinfo, the problem solved.

The code now:

client.c

```
int sockfd, sockfd2;
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
struct addrinfo hints2, *servinfo2, *p2;
int rv, rv2;
 //Opening socket
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
memset(&hints2, 0, sizeof(hints2));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints2.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints2.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[3], &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "tpgetaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
exit(1);
}

if ((rv2 = getaddrinfo(argv[2], argv[4], &hints2, &servinfo2)) != 0) {
fprintf(stderr, "rsgetaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv2));
exit(1);
}

for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
    perror("tpsocket");
    continue;
}

if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    perror("tpconnect");
    close(sockfd);
    continue;
}

break;
}

for (p2 = servinfo2; p2 != NULL; p2 = p2->ai_next) {
if ((sockfd2 = socket(p2->ai_family, p2->ai_socktype, p2->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
    perror("rssocket");
    continue;
}

if (connect(sockfd2, p2->ai_addr, p2->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    perror("rsconnect");
    close(sockfd2);
    continue;
}

break;
}

if (p == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "failed to connect tpserver\n");
exit(2);
}

if (p2 == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "failed to connect rsserver\n");
exit(2);
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
freeaddrinfo(servinfo2);
```